# Any difference between: "Did you know anybody else that old?" AND "Did you know anybody else as old?"

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

Somebody asks a very old lady "How old are you"? And she says:

**"I am 101. Did you know anybody else that old?"**  [Old lady](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69HgC2KghBc) (see:00:49-00:53)

I sometimes hear that another structure is also used when comparing two things. For instance for the case above:

**"Did you know anybody else as old?"**

When comparing things, **"....that old"** and **"....as old?"** both seem to have the same meaning.

So it seems that we can use both with no change in meaning, can we?

Comment: Can you specify usage? Because they are not (commonly) used as you described. "...that old" isn't normally a comparison between two, it means "really old". OTOH, while you can use "...as old" to compare two person, it usually comes with direct comparison, like : "Never did I see anyone as old *as you are*".

Comment: @Rakib, I added the link.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, she says "Did you *ever* know anybody else that old?" She means "Have you ever met a person of that age (101)?"

**That old** refers to a particular age. **As old [as]** is a comparison. Alice could have said "Did you ever know anybody as old as I am?"